# Strapi Ck editor plugin and nextJS image resizing not working

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, strapi, ckeditor5

I'm using CK editor plugin for strapi. The markdown module is desactivated so ck editor returns html. On the frontend i'm using react (next.js) . Everything seems to be working fine, but the resizing is not working. When I resize an image I get a `<figure>` tag with a inline size of the width of the resized image and classes `image image_resized`, however the `<img>` tag inside `<figure>` has an attribute of `sizes='100vw'`. the image is bleeding out of the `<figure>` tag and is never actually resized even though I can see the correct width is passed to `<figure>`

I checked the documentation but couldn't find anything , did I miss something ? Am I to do something on my frontend so the images resize correctly ?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Imran I did ! You need to add ck-content as a classname to your container and add the styles https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/advanced/content-styles.html

Comment: Yes I found it also

Answer (score 0):

You can just do at global styles:

```
img{width:100%;}
```

or

```
figure img{width: 100%;}
```